# Relating classes in ontology

Tags: taxonomy, jena, ontology, owl, protege

I have problems relating classes (not individuals) in my ontology. I need to know which one
OWL(full-dl-lite) allows to relate classes.
i mean the domain and range of property be http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class.
Is it possible to do that?
thanks for any hint.

Comment: @ William Niu what is your idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, forget about the spec at http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-guide/, http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/ and http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-semantics/. The official recommendation for a Web Ontology Language is [OWL 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/), where the various sublanguages are OWL 2 EL, OWL 2 QL, OWL 2 RL, OWL 2 DL and OWL 2 Full (read about the [new features of OWL 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-new-features/)). OWL Lite does not exist anymore and should be forgotten forever.

Second, in OWL (both 1 and 2), it has always been possible to relate classes using annotation properties, like this in [Turtle](http://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/):

```
# valid in all variants and OWL 1 and OWL 2
:prop  a  owl:AnnotationProperty .
:C1  a  owl:Class .
:C2  a  owl:Class;
     :prop  :C2 .
```

In OWL 1, it was not possible to define a domain or range for an annotation property but it is now possible in OWL 2:

```
# works in all variants of OWL 2
:prop  a  owl:AnnotationProperty;
       rdfs:domain  owl:Class;
       rdfs:range  owl:Class .
```

Your other option is to rely on the notion of "punning", that is, using the IRI of a class for an individual, like so:

```
# works in all variants of OWL 2
:prop  a  owl:ObjectProperty .
:C1  a  owl:Class .
:C2  a  owl:Class;
     :prop  :C2 .
```

However, you cannot use `owl:Class` as the domain or range of an object property. The last possibility is to not care and use OWL (1/2) Full:

```
# works in OWL 1 Full, OWL 2 Full
:prop  rdfs:domain  owl:Class;
       rdfs:range  owl:Class .
:C1  a  owl:Class;
     :prop  :C2 .
```

Note that most OWL DL reasoners will not crash on that input (more precisely, all reasoners that I've ever tested would not crash), so it's pretty safe in fact.

Comment: thanks for your attention. i am developing an ontology that  start from root: thing ,to the last level that include some classes. there are different relations between these classes(it seems like a graph). i can use these 2 formats,but i want to know that can i infer what i need from this ontology by using these relations format? next comment shows these formats

Comment: <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="isPartOf">
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>                                                                                      format 2

 <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:ID="isPartOf">
     <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
      <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
</owl:AnnotationProperty>

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a threaded discussion forum, it's a collection of curated answers to specific questions. If you have a follow-up query, please create a new top-level question. You can always refer to this question in your new question, if necessary.